# why are there 2 web.config files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

Why are there multiple (2) web.config files:

- 1 in the root directory
- 1 in the views directory

Comment: See also this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23509617) for more recent versions of MVC, same principle.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The web.config in the Views directory just has one significant entry, which blocks direct access:

```
<add path="*" verb="*"
      type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
```

This is so someone cannot manually try to go to `http://www.yoursite.com/views/main/index.aspx` and load the page outside the MVC pipeline.

Comment: @Rex to which file i have to add my connection string

Comment: @Pandiya the root web.config, not one in the Views dir (or any other)

Answer (score 12):

What Silky said, except reworded.

In ASP .NET there is basically an inheritance style thing going on for config files.  You have a machine.config out there in the .net framework folder which has basic settings for all apps on the machine.  Anything you specify in a root web.config with the same tags would override the stuff in the machine.config.
 **Any web.config in a sub-folder can override or add additional settings within that sub-folder and its children.**

It's always fun for me the first time one of my newer programmers puts in a http handler in a root folder and then all of the apps in the virtual directories under it explode because they don't have the DLL (they should have put the http handler statement only in the app that needed it, not in the root).  :)

Answer (score 6):

/Views/Web.config

This is not your application’s main
web.config file. It just contains a
directive instructing the web server
not to serve any *.aspx files under
/Views (because they should be
rendered by a controller, not invoked
directly like classic WebForms *.aspx
files). This file also contains configuration
needed to make the standard
ASP.NET ASPX page compiler work
properly with ASP.NET MVC view
template syntax.

/Web.config

This defines your application
configuration.

This is from the book Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework

Answer (score 4):

You can have multiple web.configs to define different settings for that folder. Used for permissions, and other such things.