# Why do I need a web.config in all view folders in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns

Trying to find a solution I read this question: [What does the Web.Config file do in the views folder of a MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204341/what-does-the-web-config-file-do-in-the-views-folder-of-a-mvc-project)

But I still want to know: *Why do I need a web.config in all view folders in MVC?*

This answer *The web.config file exists in the Views folders to prevent access to your views by any means other than your controller* is not enough for me, if it's true, it's a temporary solution.

If this is really the only reason, this is a huge point to improve. But, I'm pretty sure there is a good reason for that.

Comment: I found this post to have some useful answers:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355353/why-are-there-2-web-config-files][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355353/why-are-there-2-web-config-files

Comment: This is aim of my question! Shame on MVC if the only reason is: `The web.config in the Views directory just has one significant entry, which blocks direct access`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, yes, I agree.  In another answer in the same thread this reason is given:

> This file also contains configuration needed to make the standard
>   ASP.NET ASPX page compiler work properly with ASP.NET MVC view
>   template syntax.

So I infer there are some backward compatibility issues that may need to be worked out.
But I do agree with your central point that this is something that should be improved upon in future iterations.

Comment: *This was meant to be a comment to the original question, not an answer.  *Sorry!