# Why are there two web.config files in my MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, iis-7, httphandler

There is one in the Views folder.

And there is another in the root of the app.

I want to register a custom handler and i cant understand where the code should go.
I'm running IIS7 in Integrated Mode so I have to add a `<handlers>` tag to the `<system.webServer>` but when I'm looking at the web.config at the Views folder I see that it uses a `<httpHandlers>` under `<system.web>` tag.

So two questions:
  1. why are there two web.config files in an mvc application?
  2. where and in what way I should register my custom HTTP Handler?

Comment: possible duplicate of [why are there 2 web.config files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355353/why-are-there-2-web-config-files)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should register it in root config. Views config is for configure views, for example: add namespace for all views and etc.

- [ASP.NET MVC and two Web.config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517086/asp-net-mvc-and-two-web-config-files)
- [why are there 2 web.config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355353/why-are-there-2-web-config-files)