# Compilation errors whenever open any of View files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was working on back-end of existing ASP .NET MVC project for some time and all of it was building splendidly.

But now as time came for some front-end, as soon as I open (just open) one of the views it all starts glowing red and the project doesn't build anymore with numerous errors as:

> CS0246    The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> CS8023    Feature 'lambda expression' is not available in C# 2.  Please use language version 3 or greater.
>
> CS0012    The type 'WebViewPage<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

I have triple checked I have all the references. How could I possibly resolve the issue?

Comment: Have you tried Cleaning your Solution? Build > Clean Solution. Then try and build.

Comment: Likely there is a reference in the web.config file that is in the Views folder and it conflicts with the version of the System.Web.Mvc assembly that is referenced.

Comment: @JamieR Sure, it works if none of the views are opned.

Comment: @GlennFerrie I have no web.config in the View folder.

Comment: @AntonioBlack, not having a web.config in the view folder might be the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509617/why-does-net-generate-two-web-config-files-in-an-mvc-asp-net-application